# How to sign out so that when the page is rendered it does not know the user is authenticated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When I sign out using this controller:

```
public class LogOffController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return View();
    }
}
```

The rendered page does not know I have been signed out, and in part of razor page I display the user:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  <text>Welcome <strong>@Profile.GetPropertyValue("FullName")</strong> 
  @if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
  {
     @Html.ActionLink("(Administrator)", "Index", "Administration")
  } 
  [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "Index", "LogOff") ]</text>
}
else
{
  @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Index", "Login")
}
```

This still displays the users name and administrator role like they are logged on still. The next page I navigate to is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dave Zych method is a prefer way of doing it. However, if you want to display LogOff View like in your original question, you can insert null to current thread's principal object.

```
public class LogOffController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        HttpContext.User = null;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = null;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, `HttpContext.User = null;` was the only required line. Any reason to use the `Thread` line as well?

Comment: If `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is not null, `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` will be true. If your code never access `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, you are fine. However, you might want to include that too because if next developer comes in and uses `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, it'll make the big security hole.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a View, use `RedirectToAction` or `RedirectToRoute`.

```
public class LogOffController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great alternative suggestion, and I will be using this, but the other answer answers the question of how to do it should you need to.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `HttpContext.User` is set when ASP.NET pipeline reads the value from authentication cookies. When you do `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` - you just tell the browser to delete authentication cookies, but it knows nothing about .NET current user.
In order to resolve it you have two choices:

- Redirect user to other page so your request go through pipeline again
  and .NET know if user is authenticated.
- Logout user manually:

  ```
  var currentUser = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);
  HttpContext.User = currentUser;
  Thread.CurrentPrincipal = currentUser;
  ```

  Note that you shouldn't assign `null` as current user because on the view you could encounter call of some property on `User`, for example `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.